# SwiftyDropbox API Operation Failed Externally to Library

Tags: swift, xcode, dropbox, swiftydropbox

I am attempting to upload an image to dropbox through the swiftydropbox API but when I call the uploadFile method I get the following error:
2018-07-02 15:52:16.947075-0400 takePicBrianAdvent2[872:568330] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2878 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library

Comment: FWIW, I have the same error when uploading to Firebase, which also uses BoringSSL.